# How intercept submit form?

Tags: javascript, angular

My project have follow reactive form:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="line">
    <input class="title" id="title" placeholder="Заголовок вопроса" type="text" formControlName="title">
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <textarea class="question" name="question" id="question" placeholder="Текст вопроса" formControlName="question" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <div class="tags">
      <span class="title">Метки</span>
      <span class="tag" *ngFor="let tag of tags">{{ tag }} <span class="delete" (click)="deleteTag(tag)">X</span></span>
    </div>
    <input class="tag" id="tag" placeholder="Введите тег и нажмите enter" type="text" formControlName="tag" #tag (keyup.enter)="addTag($event, tag.value)">
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <button class="btn btn-common" type="submit" mat-button [disabled]="form.invalid">
      Отправить
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This form initialized in component:

```
private form: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      'title':      new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]),
      'question':   new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
      'tag':        new FormControl()
    });
  }
```

In field #tag user write tagname and press Enter key. And form is submit. But i need cancel form submit after press Enter key.

my attempt:

```
  private addTag(event, tag): void {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    if(!tag.trim().length) { return; }

    this.form.patchValue({tag: ''});

    if(this.tags.indexOf(tag) === -1) {
      this.tags.push(tag.trim());
    }
  }
```

But this does not stop submiting the form. I need cancel submit form after press Enter key

Comment: Please check my answer. I've added working example

Answer (score 1):

`keyup` event is too late to catch submit.

I would handle `keydown` event:

**html**

```
(keydown.enter)="addTag($event, tag.value)"
```

**ts**

```
private addTag(event, tag): void {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

or you can return `false`

**html**

```
(keydown.enter)="!!addTag(tag.value)"
                ^^^^
            convert to boolean
```

**ts**

```
addTag(tag): void {
  if(!tag.trim().length) { return; }

  this.form.patchValue({tag: ''});

  if(this.tags.indexOf(tag) === -1) {
    this.tags.push(tag.trim());
  }
}
```

**[Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/JtPoYt9XbBLSG8O0qBXV)**